# How to add Node<Integer> list to get average?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am supposed to create a method that calculates the average. I can't figure out why i am having so much trouble. My list has a set of random numbers generated but i keep getting an error in my method saying " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Node.avg(Node.java:58)
    at Node.main(Node.java:51)"

```
public class Node<T> 
{
private T       data;  // data portion
private Node<T> next;  // link to next node

public Node(T dataPortion)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    next = null;    
} // end constructor

public Node(T dataPortion, Node<T> nextNode)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    next = nextNode;    
} // end constructor

public T getData()
{
    return data;
} // end getData

public void setData(T newData)
{
    data = newData;
} // end setData

public Node<T> getNextNode()
{
    return next;
} // end getNextNode

public void setNextNode(Node<T> nextNode)
{
    next = nextNode;
} // end setNextNode
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer num;
    LList<Integer> firstNode = new LList<Integer>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter ++)
    {
        num = new Integer((int)(Math.random() * 100));
        firstNode.add(num);
        avg(firstNode);
    }

}
public static int avg(LList<Integer> firstNode)
{
    int count = 0, total = 0;
    int avg = total/count;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        total += ((ListInterface<Integer>) firstNode).getEntry(i);
        count++;
    }
    return avg;
```

Comment: your count variable value is 0. Indeed you will get Divide By Zero error for the statement avg=total/count

Comment: You want your average to be a `double`, not an `int`, or you'll run into integer division.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to calculate the average before you find out what the count and the total is.

Right now, you're doing:

```
int count = 0, total = 0;
int avg = total / count;
// for loop to find count and total
return avg
```

When you try and find the average, total and count are still equal to zero so naturally you end up with a divide by zero exception. Instead, do the division after the loop:

```
public static int avg(LList<Integer> firstNode)
{
    int count = 0, total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        total += ((ListInterface<Integer>) firstNode).getEntry(i);
        count++;
    }
    return total / count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can divid anything by zero

you divided `total/count` which both are initialized with 0

you should find avg after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do the division after the for loop, otherwise it is clear that `count` is zero:

```
int count = 0, total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    total += ((ListInterface<Integer>) firstNode).getEntry(i);
    count++;
}
int avg = total/count;
return avg;
```

Moreover, the average is likely a real number, not an integer. So the calculation is better done as:

```
double avg = ((double)total) / count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in here:

```
int count = 0, total = 0;
int avg = total/count; //HERE
```

You are initializing count to 0 and then trying to divide by 0 to initialize the avg. That will fail every single time.